# ParsePlatform - How to query for a time window?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

What I'm attempting to do is get one row per hour of data in a date range. I've seen some examples using sql, that I dont' think I can do with the android ParsePlatform library...

So my thought is maybe there is a way to query for all rows where the timestamp is within +- 5 minutes of 00, is that possible, or how might I accomplish my end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `whereLessThanOrEqualTo` functions for that. It would be something like this:

```java
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName");
query.whereGreaterThan("yourDateFieldName", new Date(someDate.getTimeInMillis() - 5 * 60 * 1000));
query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("yourDateFieldName", new Date(someDate.getTimeInMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000));
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback< ParseObject >() {
  void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    // results has the list of objects matching the query
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return only one result? The idea is to get one row for each hour over many days.

Comment: It will return all rows in a time range. You'd need to perform many of these queries for different time ranges. You can also try to use aggregate and try to retrieve everything on a single query: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to query over the range. Filtering to one per hour and trying to minimize queries is what prompted this question... Aggregate sounds promising. Thanks!